# Sorting in python- How to sort in a different order?

Tags: python, sorting

What is the python implementation to Sort this list:

```
['a', 'C', 2, 'z', 'B', 1, 'h', 0, 'Y', 9]
```

into the below list?

```
['a', 'B', 'C', 'h', 'Y', 'z', 9, 2, 1, 0]
```

Order: a->b->..->y->z->...3->-2->1->0

It is Case insensitive for letters ('A' is same as 'a').

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Specify a proper *key* function using *sorted* should do it with the given list:

```
lst = ['a', 'C', 2, 'z', 'B', 1, 'h', 0, 'Y', 9]
sorted(lst, key = lambda x: (not isinstance(x, str), x.lower() if isinstance(x, str) else -x))

# ['a', 'B', 'C', 'h', 'Y', 'z', 9, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped alot!